# Link Sharepoint Survey to External list

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

I am trying to go around the limitation of not being able to associate workflows to external lists.

I am wondering if it is possible to create some form of association with a SharePoint survey.

My business requirement is the following;

My external list contains help desk tickets, i.e. ticketID1, ticketID2, etc. And for each of these records I need to associate it with my survey list "Help Desk Survey". From then on, I would need to create a workflow that would send an email to the user related to the that help desk ticket.

Is there an automated way of creating this association?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the ticket creator to fill out the survey once the ticket has been resolved? So you could just add an Email notification workflow that would include a link to the survey once ticket status is resolved.

Comment: This ticket table is presented in SharePoint as external list. if I cannot associate, (by limitation), workflows to the external list, how do I add an email notification for the user ?

Comment: Where is your external list located? Is it not housed in Sharepoint as a custom list?

Comment: This list is a SQL table presented in SharePoint using BCS as an "external list".

Comment: Got it. Have you tried the following method? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/01/20/using-sharepoint-workflows-with-business-connectivity-services-bcs.aspx

Comment: I did but this example does not apply to my business scenario. In this example there is a direct relationship between EmployeeID from the main SharePoint list and the and EmployeeID from the external list. My scenario I have the external list populated with a bunch of new tickets every day that need to send an email to those people to fill out 1 survey.